# QGIS 3.10 Issue on Export Selected Feature

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, export

I recently come across a weird issue when performing "[Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location)" and then "Exporting selected features".

Basically, I have a large dataset (points) and a target area (polygon). I just need to select all points within the polygon. Sounds pretty easy and straight forward.

Firstly, I run "Select by location" and get around 74K features selected.
Secondly, I export those points by "right click -> export -> save selected features as".
Then, the exporting task will run for approx 15 mins but give me a complete empty layer!

I tried the same step on small datasets and the export works fine.
Does anyone have any advice?

[image]

Comment: What is the format of the output data?

Comment: I tried shp and csv, neither of them work

Comment: Just to accomplish what you need to do, could you try using Extract by Location and see if you get any results?

Comment: @she_weeds  Yeah, "Extract by Location" works perfectly !!!! Awesome!!!

Comment: Hi, this looks more like a bug report, which is suited for https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/